# Columnpartitioner for composite primay key tables?

Tags: spring-batch

In my case, I have to load huge data from one table to another. (Tera to sqlserver). Using `JdbcCursorItemReader`,  on avg it takes 30 mins to load 200000 records since the table has 40 columns. So I am planning to use the partition technique.

Below are the challenges

1. The table has a composite primary key (2 columns).
2. And one of the column values having negative values.
3. Is this possible to do columnpartition technique in this case?
4. I see the columnpartition technique uses one primary key and finding max and min values. In my case, with composite primary , even if i figure someway for max, min, grid size. will the framework support to handle the composite primarykey for doing paritioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things to note here:

1. `JdbcCursorItemReader` is not thread safe so it typically isn't used in partitioning scenarios.  Instead the `JdbcPagingItemReader` is used.
2. Your logic to partition the data is purely up to you.  While doing it via values in a column is useful, it doesn't apply to all use cases (like this one).  In this specific use case, you may want to partition by `ROW_NUMBER()` or something similar, or add a column to partition by.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the response. I was not able to use the pagingItemReader method since it was throwing  'org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean#143a680': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [Teradata]. There is no support bean for teradata - SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.

Comment: And I tried to give a sqlserver datasource as property for the  SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.  and teradata source for jdbcpageItemReader . It started working but not sure whether it should be fine to use. please let me know.